# AWS Lambda - How do i invoke different functions from 2 different cloud watch triggers

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have a lambda function running with a cloud watch trigger with rate-5 that pulls data via an API and inserts it into a database. I want to add another cloud watch trigger to a report generator once per day. The code i have is something like this

```
def run_data_capture():
    data = api_call()
    insert_data(data)

def run_generate_report():
    data = query_table()
    csv = generate_csv(data)

def handler(event, context):
   run_data_capture()
```

The handler is the method my lambda function is invoking. If i add another cloudwatch trigger to run once per day, how do i figure out which trigger is invoking the handler so that i could do something like:

```
def hander(event, context):
    if 5MinuteEvent:
        run_data_capture()
    elif dailyEvent:
        run_generate_report()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a lambda function is called the event that calls it is passed to the handler as the event object.

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) is the Amazon example of calling a lambda function. They give

```
{
"version": "0",
"id": "53dc4d37-cffa-4f76-80c9-8b7d4a4d2eaa",
"detail-type": "Scheduled Event",
"source": "aws.events",
"account": "123456789012",
"time": "2015-10-08T16:53:06Z",
"region": "us-east-1",
"resources": [
    "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:123456789012:rule/my-scheduled-rule"
],
"detail": {}
}
```

as an example of a object passed from coudwatch to lambda. If you parse the object and compare the "detail-type" data or "source" it will give you the information you need to figure out what cloudwatch function is invoking the lambda function. Example:

```
def handler(event, context):
   event_type = event['source']
   if event_type == '5MinuteEvent':
       run_data_capture()
   elif event_type == 'dailyEvent':
       run_generate_report()
```

Comment: Cool thanks for the help. I decided to go with looking directly at which rule is being invoked (event['resources'][0]) because im going to have a few different events triggering the function